# ruby on rails - Every syntax of rails create a new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debian

I installed Ruby on Rails on my Debian Server.
Ruby Version => 2.0.0
Rails Version => 3.2.13

If i want to update all my gem's with the command:

```
gem update
```

it give's me as answer:

```
ERROR:  Error installing actionmailer:
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
Updating actionpack
ERROR:  Error installing actionpack:
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
Updating activerecord
ERROR:  Error installing activerecord:
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

But i have a newer version as 1.9.3...
And if I want to create a new project with the command

```
rails new project
```

It creates me a project called 'new'..

It seem's that Rails does not know the controller... Because when I type:

```
rails generate controller Show index
```

He creates me a new **project** with the name generate

Here are my informations:

```
Ruby Version => 2.0.0
Rails Version => 3.2.13
rvm Version => 1.21.6
```

Comment: `rails generate controller controller_name action_name1 action_name2`  so like `rails generate users show index` thanks

Comment: No The controller name is called 'show'
So if i type in rails generate controller Show index.. he creates me a new project with the name generate

Comment: I SAID IF I TYPE IN: rails generate controller Show index
He create's me a application with the name generate!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because, in your system there is rails 2 also installed and rails 2 is your default rails. The syntax for creating project in rails 2 is simply "rails project_name" that's why every time you are running **rails** either for generating controller, model or anything...the project is creating

uninstall ruby and rails completely and follow this link to install rails in your system:
[How to install Ruby on Rails on linux](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-from-source) 
OR

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

Oh! I forgot to tell, you can install Ruby Version Manager (RVM) instead.

may be this can help

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is 1.9.3, but *rubygems* is older.

On Ubuntu 12.04, for example, try this:

```
apt-get remove rubygems 
apt-get install rubygems1.9
```

And try again